# Track/trace a used (invoked) package function/procedure or fire event on a particular package sub-program call

Tags: oracle, logging, plsql, trace, auditing

I am a newbie to Oracle. I have been assigned to find all used packages, functions and procedures used by the (client) system (legacy system). I have found a solution to that by using AUDIT. The problem is that the AUDIT does not allow us to trace/track package functions or procedures - that is I have a list of packages and function/procedures used by our client system now, but what I should do now is to find functions and procedures used (or not used by the client system) inside the list of those packages. In other words, how one can track or log function/procedure of a package invoked (used).

I reference DBMS_TRACE and DBMS_PROFILE to determine which  function/procedure is invoked, but they do not give me information about package and its corresponding sub-program(s). The solution should give me information about sub-program unit called (used) by the clientside - that is it should not only give me package reference (since I have got packages used), but also give me the packages' sub-program run(called/invoked).

Or is there any way to fire a kind of trigger/event on a package/package subprogram called.

Could anyone help me please? Could be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for actual invocations, or where they are referenced in code? Which version of Oracle - in 11g PL/Scope might help you.

Comment: To clarify, let us say we have a package called PACKAGE1. Inside the package there could be any number of functions/procedures. So I should determine whether a function/procedure is used or invoked when I run the client system (as I mentioned above, I have already got those packages invoked), but what I need to find a specific list of functions/procedures invoked or run by our client system .

Comment: Are you looking for [dependencies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1069.htm#REFRN20053)?

Comment: Or is there any way to fire an event on a particular package function/procedure call, like on other high level languages, like calling a function fires an event that I could be informed which procedure is invoked.

Comment: No Ben, I am looking for a function/procedure inside the package (packages' procedures/functions), not what kind of functions it calls or uses.

Comment: I can find all funcitons inside any package, but the problem is that I cannot find which one of them is called or used when running from the client side.